# Expose ContentPlaceHolder in User Control

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am implementing a web application and i faced the following problem:

I have a User control with it's own styles and js files, when i add the user control to the page and i try to validate the murkup i get error due to the fact that the user control's styles and js are in the body of the page in stead of the head. i would like to expose the page head to add from my web application user controls the styles and js files directly into the page head. have you got any suggestion?
i did not get any good solution online yet

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In the user control markup you can put place holder with all css and js references you need like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phStyles" runat="server">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/App_Themes/Default/style/MyStyles.css" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Than in the user control's code behind you can add the place holder to the page's controls colection:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(phStyles);
    }
```

The only condition is that on the Page the head tag must have runat="server" like this:

```
<head runat="server">
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

Scott Gu [wrote](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/03/24/Access-to-a-page_2700_s-head-element-using-ASP.NET-2.0.aspx) a post about this. You may try the following:

```
HtmlGenericControl script = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
script.Attributes.Add("src", "/somescript.js");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @darin-dimitrov's answer and made a loop to find the Content control on the Master page, since I wanted to put mine in a Footer and not in a Header:

```
var scriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
scriptTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
scriptTag.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ResolveUrl($"~/somescript.js"));

Control control = null;
MasterPage master = Page.Master;

while (master != null)
{
    control = master.FindControl("FooterContent");
    if (control == null)
        master = master.Master;
    else
        break;
}
control.Controls.Add(scriptTag);
```