# Can a ContentPlaceHolder be placed in a Web User Control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webusercontrol, contentplaceholder

**I want to do something like this:**

I got this User Control called Base:

```
<div>
some content...

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="baseContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</div>
```

Then i inherit the Base in another User Control and add stuff to the content:

```
<asp:Content id="subBase" contentplaceholderid="baseContentPlaceHolder" runat"server">
    stuff to be added...
</asp:Content>
```

**Is it possible to do with ContentPlaceHolder ?**

**How can this behavior be solved?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

A `ContentPlaceHolder` can only go in the MasterPage itself.

In the pages that inherit from the MasterPage, you put in a `Content` tag.

My best guess would be to add in a `PlaceHolder`, expose that on the control, and then add in your stuff to that.

Comment: Yep, You can't use a ContentPlaceHolder in a User Control, but just to clarify yes you can add the contents of regular PlaceHolder to the page from within a user control, or add/modify the contents of a regular PlaceHolder in a derived UserControl.  example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1973773/132461

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the Master pages until you find the `ContentPlaceHolder` and insert it there:

```
var scriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
scriptTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
scriptTag.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ResolveUrl($"~/somescript.js"));

Control control = null;
MasterPage master = Page.Master;

while (master != null)
{
    control = master.FindControl("FooterContent");
    if (control == null)
        master = master.Master;
    else
        break;
}
control.Controls.Add(scriptTag);
```